Nginx how to set shell function executing result in response header
I wish to set a dynamic param in response header, such as get some linux status in client, need to get shell function excute result. Until now I only get the method to set static headers params.
How to run a shell script on every request?
Add dynamic response headers from a file
Nginx add_header for a 50* page
